Python module-level function naming best practices
Suppose I have two modules boat and car, each with similar functions related to accessing/modifying objects in a database. I have a couple options for naming such functions:

Assume the modules are imported as import boat, car, so that the functions can be named assuming module context, i.e. car.get, boat.get, boat.delete, etc.
Assume the functions will be imported as from car import a, b, ..., so name the functions assuming no module context is available, i.e. get_car, get_boat, delete_boat, etc.

My preference is for option 1 but I'm wondering if there is a documented convention somewhere--I haven't seen one.

This is opinion based, but generally it is preferable to import the module and access functions and classes from the module namespace, i.e.: car.get

If you're looking for somewhere questions of best-practice are explicitly on-topic, see our sister site [softwareengineering.se].

Both options have their merits, but it's crucial to follow Python's conventions for clarity and maintainability.
Module Context Importing: Importing modules directly (import boat, car) and using functions with module context (boat.get, car.delete) is explicit and prevents naming conflicts. It aligns with Python's philosophy.
Module-Level Imports with Aliasing: Alternatively, you can use module-level imports with aliasing (import boat as boat_module). This maintains clarity while providing convenience.
Consider creating a common base class or utilizing composition if car and boat share similar functionalities. This promotes code reusability and maintainability.
I recommend you to read PEP 8, it is a great python style guide

Note in How to Answer the section Answer Well-Asked Questions, and therein the link to https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic; questions about what's a good or bad practice (as opposed to what does and doesn't work as an objectively correct solution to a specific, practical problem) are frowned on here, but on-topic at our sister site [softwareengineering.se].
